# Is it possible to add an optional reference on a non-nullable column?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I have two tables (`endorsement` and `work_data`) in my database that both reference objects ("works") external to my project, i.e. that have an ID (`pid`) that is not defined by me (compare e.g. ISBNs for books).

For every work that exists, I can add an `endorsement`, `work_data`, both, or neither.

Now my question is: can I and should I add a foreign key linking the `pid` columns of both `endorsement` and `work_data`, given that either may or may not have rows about that `pid`? I'd like to be able to efficiently fetch `work_data`, if available, for a work referenced by a given `endorsement`, and vice versa.

I'm using PostgreSQL if it matters.

**Edit:** As requested, an example. Typed by heart, so don't mind syntax errors - I'm wondering about database design, and what considerations to take into account regarding the efficiency of what I want to do.

`endorsement`:

```
| pid | user |
| -- | -- |
| 10.0000/00 | 1 |
| 10.1111/11 | 1 |
```

(So user `1` has endorsed two works.)

`work_data`:

```
| pid | title |
| -- | -- |
| 10.1111/11 | 'Some article that has an endorsement' |
| 10.2222/22 | 'Some other article that does not have an endorsement' |
```

(So we know of two works, one of which is also listed in the `endorsement` table.)

Now I'd like to be able to select endorsements, with the joined data, e.g.

```
SELECT endorsement.*, pid.title FROM endorsement LEFT JOIN work_data ON endorsement.pid=work_data.pid;

| pid | user | title |
| -- | -- | -- |
| 10.0000/00 | 1 | NULL |
| 10.1111/11 | 1 | 'Some article that has an endorsement' |
```

Likewise, I'd like to be able to select work data, with the joined endorsements, e.g.

```
SELECT work_data.*, endorsement.user FROM work_data LEFT JOIN endorsement ON work_data.pid=endorsement.pid;

| pid | title | user |
| -- | -- | -- |
| 10.1111/11 | 'Some article that has an endorsement' | 1 |
| 10.2222/22 | 'Some other article that does not have an endorsement' | NULL |
```

Comment: What would the `pid` reference?  Sample data and desired results would help.

Comment: @GordonLinoff A DOI, i.e. an identifier for a scholarly article, comparable to how books have an ISBN. I've added some sample data to the question.

Comment: Rule of thumb: Store references to *external* data only once, and use a surrogate key to refer to them. (a poor man's data-vault)

Comment: @joop Do you mean that whenever I want to insert either an `endorsement` or `work_data`, I first have to check whether a surrogate key already exists for that work, if it doesn't, create that key, and only _after_ that do the actual insert?

Comment: Assuming `works` is in the same database as your data, is it OK for you to create side-effect to the other project (`DELETE FROM works WHERE ...` will now have to look into your 2 tables)? To me, it would be but if it is not OK for **you/the guys from the other project**, then you can stop thinking about FKs immediately.

Comment: Yes, but it is basically the same: in both cases the FK has to be present in the referred-to table. But the surrogate key allows the *external* key value to change without cascading into your own tables. (the *external* key most probably needs a UNIQUE constraint) And: you can't have a FK to a non-existing table; it has to be stored somewhere in *your* schema.

Comment: @user10600584 No, works are externally defined, just like how e.g. books have ISBNs.

Comment: But: books could exist in your inventory without you knowing the ISBN. Or even: with the wong ISBN.

Comment: @joop The external key will never change, that's guaranteed by the external party (DOI). As for your final remark: what "non-existing table" are you referring to? Both `endorsement` and `work_data` are existing tables. Their rows refer to the same work, so I'd like to be able to fetch rows from both for a given work, but neither table guarantees that they have rows on that work.

Comment: FK are built to enfore referential integrity within your database; IMHO with external data, it will be awfully complicated (see @joop suggestion). If **all** you want is fetch data efficiently, create an index.

Comment: @joop I don't quite follow that... Isn't that dependent on the use case? I don't want to have rows referring to DOIs that do not exist, that doesn't fit my application.

Comment: They both refer to `works`, which should exist, obviously.

Comment: @user10600584 Thanks, yes: all I want is to fetch data efficiently, I don't necessarily need to enforce referential integrity. If I create an index on pid on both columsn, is a `LEFT JOIN` on either efficient?

Comment: @joop Why should it exist? Users are not allowed to define works themselves. What would the purpose of such a table be?

Comment: `I don't necessarily need to enforce referential integrity.` Use a spreadsheet and weep later.

Comment: (Btw, I realise this might come off as argumentative - I don't intend it to. I'm just trying to ask follow-up questions to increase my currently limited understanding.)

Comment: @joop Obviously there are other parts of my application in which I _do_ want to preserve referential integrity, but in regards to works, my application just assumes that `pid`s refer to valid works. If they do happen to refer to invalid works, that would not be problematic.

Comment: Creating indexes is what I would do indeed. However, it is not always guaranteed indexes are used in queries (see https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/performance-tips.html). This is something you will have to test (More details would be needed for me to answer that question).